# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when running jest in TypeScript CRA project

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have a `create-react-app` project with TypeScript. I recently added a couple of packages (specifically `material-ui-dropzone` and `@azure/storage-blob`) to my project, and suddenly all my tests are failing because of a `SyntaxError` in a file I haven't really touched. I've seen other people having problems with es6 imports and babel transformation, but this error seems a little different. `yarn start` and `yarn build` work without any problems. Here's the output from `yarn test`:

```
/<projectPath>/src/Shared/utils/authorizer.ts:27
    private constructor() {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
     9 | import Log from 'Core/debugLog/Log';
    10 | import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';
  > 11 | import { Authorizer } from 'Shared/utils/authorizer';
       | ^
    12 | import { AppInsights } from 'Shared/utils/appInsights';
    13 | import { OperationDefinitionNode } from 'graphql';
    14 |
    at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
    at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (src/Core/graphql/graphQlConfig.ts:11:1)
```

In my jest config in `package.json` I have only a couple of configs related to coverage.

I tried running `yarn upgrade`, and noticed a lot of babel dependencies upgrading from 7.5.5 to 7.7.2, but the same problem persists.

Please ask if there is any other information I can give to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by adding `ts-jest`:

```sh
yarn add -D ts-jest
```

And adding this under `"jest"` in `package.json`:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
},
```